# Vector works in console but not defined when run from the text editor

Tags: scripting

I was trying to scale a bunch of objects with a script and I tried this line on the console :

```
thing.scale= Vector((1, 1, 1))
```

It works fine and set the scale of the object to 1 but then I tried to use the same code in a loop on the text editor and I got an error saying that `Vector` is not defined :

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\w3D-mqbaka\Mobiverse\looop__\f_cking_modif\08.blend\scale_the_big_ones.py", line 6, in <module>
  NameError: name 'Vector' is not defined
```

This is the code I tried to run :

```
import bpy;

visible_objects=[ob for ob in bpy.context.view_layer.objects if (ob.visible_get() and ob.type== 'MESH')];

for stuff in visible_objects:
    stuff.scale= Vector((1, 1, 1));#reset scale
    if (stuff.dimensions.z >= 0.3):
        stuff.scale= Vector((1/stuff.dimension.z, 1/stuff.dimension.z, 1/stuff.dimension.z));
        stuf.scale= Vector((1/3, 1/3, 1/3));
```

My question is not how to makie the code working since I know that I can just remplace `Vector((1, 1, 1))` by `(1, 1, 1)` and the code will run with the expected outcome.

**My question is why is `Vector` running on the console and not on the text editor?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually quite simple. While typing my question, I scrolled on my console to see if I imported a pyhton library that would have `Vector` defined in until I got to the top and saw the console welcome text that says :

```
PYTHON INTERACTIVE CONSOLE 3.10.2 (main, Jan 27 2022, 08:34:43) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]

Builtin Modules:       bpy, bpy.data, bpy.ops, bpy.props, bpy.types, bpy.context, bpy.utils, bgl, blf, mathutils
Convenience Imports:   from mathutils import *; from math import *
Convenience Variables: C = bpy.context, D = bpy.data
```

Which says that the **math** and **mathutils** library that define `Vector` has already been **preimported in the console for convenience** but one need to import it manually when typing a script in the text editor.